# Get sister element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to get a next element from a current sister element? Sorry if confusing.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="paDiv">
       <div class="saDivOne">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="paDivTwo">
       <div class="saDivTwo">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
$('.paDiv').each(function(){
    htmlContent = $(this).children().html();
    SisterDivContent = $(this).next('.paDivTwo').children().html();
    console.log(SisterDivContent);
})
</script>
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. Which element do you want to retrieve. The code you posted functions as expected for me. (It retrieves the HTML of the children of the `div` with class `paDivTwo`.)

Comment: Your code should work, what is the problem?

Comment: I can't get the html of SisterDivContent.

Comment: The target element doesn't have any content.

Comment: Um, that code works...There is nothing for it to display since there is no html in the children...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.paDiv').each(function(){   
var SisterDivContent = $(this).parent().find('.saDivTwo').html();
alert(SisterDivContent);
});
```

You have to add some contents inside div class 'saDivTwo'. Otherwise you will get empty content only.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/U8n7g/

Comment: @Brian if this works, than your orginal code was looking at the wrong thing....Only difference is this is not looking at the children.

Answer (score 1):

Try using .sibling:

`$('.paDiv').sibling('paDivTwo').html()`